# SQL using a WHERE statement with an aggregate function

Tags: sql, count, group-by, aggregate-functions, where-clause

The following code runs exactly the way I want it to. Now I need to achieve the same task but only showing results with a COUNT greater than 1. The COUNT is meant to count the amount of rows in the allocation table of each distinct book id (bid).

```
Prompt Task 1E7;
SELECT B.bid,title,COUNT(*)
FROM ALLOCATION A
INNER JOIN BOOK B
ON A.bid = B.bid
GROUP BY B.bid,title
ORDER BY COUNT(*),bid;
```

I tried simply putting a WHERE COUNT(*) > 1 in a few different locations. This just returns the error "SQL command not properly ended" for the WHERE line. I also tried the following.

```
Prompt Task 1E7;
SELECT B.bid,title,COUNT(*)
FROM ALLOCATION A
INNER JOIN BOOK B
ON A.bid = B.bid
GROUP BY B.bid,title
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM ALLOCATION A
INNER JOIN BOOK B
ON A.bid = B.bid
GROUP BY B.bid,title) > 1
ORDER BY COUNT(*),bid;
```

and any other number of little tweaks.

Comment: When you use group by, you usually are going to use `having`, instead of `where`. Look up the difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the `HAVING` clause, which filters by values after the rollup in `GROUP BY`

Comment: Shit. I kid you not, I just discovered HAVING. T__T

Answer (score 2):

Aggregates can be filtered with `HAVING`:

```
SELECT  B.bid, title, COUNT(*) cnt
FROM    ALLOCATION A
INNER JOIN
        BOOK B
ON      A.bid = B.bid
GROUP BY
        B.bid, title
HAVING  COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER BY
        cnt, bid;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the HAVING clause just like other posters suggested. 
For future reference, this is a very good reference for SQL commands: http://www.1keydata.com/sql/sql.html